# Check if item of list is missing in other 2D list with comprehension

Tags: python, list, 2d, list-comprehension

The first list contains filenames with extensions:

```
afiles = [['file1', '.exe'], ['file2', '.txt']]
```

The second list contains filenames without extension. e.g.:

```
bfiles = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4']
```

I know want to know which files of bfiles are missing in afiles. The expected result should be:

```
['file3', 'file4']
```

I'd like to realize this with comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just try this simple list comprehension :)

```
>>> afiles = [['file1', '.exe'], ['file2', '.txt']]
>>> bfiles = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4']
>>> [x for x in bfiles if x not in (y[0] for y in afiles)]
['file3', 'file4']
```

or better, you could just assign the `afiles` files without extensions like,

```
>>> afiles_names = [x[0] for x in afiles]
>>> [x for x in bfiles if x not in afiles_names] # so you won't have to compute that each time
['file3', 'file4']
```

Comment: `in` works faster with sets: `afiles_names = {x[0] for x in afiles}`

Comment: @MykolaZotko I don't know about that `$ python -m timeit '[x for x in range(10) if x in {4,5,6}]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.66 usec per loop
 $ python -m timeit '[x for x in range(10) if x in [4,5,6]]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 usec per loop`

Comment: Try to `timeit` with `list(range(1000))` and `set(range(1000))`

Comment: I mean, we were talking about which one will `in` works faster :).  Anyway, i did the timeit `$ python -m timeit "list(range(1000))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.9 usec per loop
 $ python -m timeit "set(range(1000))"
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.2 usec per loop`

Comment: Try `[x for x in [500, 750, 999] if x in list(range(1000))]` and the same with set.

Comment: The list creation will take some significant time. Then i suggest one just use  `dict.fromkeys(keys, 0)` and membership test will certainly will be faster, i think :)

Answer (score 2):

Just check if items of bfiles fail to be found in any zero indexes in afiles.

```
afiles = [['file1', '.exe'], ['file2', '.txt']]
bfiles = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4']

result = [file for file in bfiles if not any(file == afile[0] for afile in afiles)]
['file3', 'file4']
```

Answer (score 2):

List-comprehension with `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

afiles = [['file1', '.exe'], ['file2', '.txt']]
bfiles = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4']

print([x for x in bfiles if x not in chain.from_iterable(afiles)])
# ['file3', 'file4']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the set method `difference()`:

```
set(bfiles).difference(i[0] for i in afiles)
# {'file4', 'file3'}
```